# How to find pairs in an array that all equal to the same number?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array, for example: [1, 2, 3, 2], how can I write an algorithm that pairs the numbers together (given that the input array is even) so that all pairs have the same sum?
For the example, the pairs would be: [[1,3],[2,2]] because the sum of each pair is the same (4).

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can sort the array and pair the elements one from the beginning and one from the end. I used the sorted() function but writing a custom merge sort for this will be more efficient since I had to iterate the list again to pair the elements. Complexity is O(n*log(n)).

```
def equal_pair(arr):
    sorted_array = sorted(arr)
    equal_pairs = []
    pair_sum = (2*sum(arr))/len(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr) // 2):
        if sorted_array[i] + sorted_array[-(i + 1)] == pair_sum:
            equal_pairs.append([sorted_array[i], sorted_array[-(i + 1)]])
        else:
            return "Equal Pairs not possible "

    return equal_pairs


print(equal_pair([1, 2, 3, 2]))
```